# How to sort values in pandas DataFrame based on a few columns without column prority?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort pandas df by values without priority of particular column. I've attached the image with expected result. In this case, index '2' has 0,99 value, so we put it at the first place. Then, we put '4' at the second row because it contains 0,95 value(independently of exact column) etc. How can I apply such kind of sorting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIuJH.jpg)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to sort the rows by their highest occurrence for the first column, then proceed to the next column, and so on, without re-sorting the uppermost row(s) for the columns that came before?

Comment: Rather independent of the sequence of columns. Just by the fact that the largest value entered the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the maximum values of each row, then get the indices that would sort them in descending order with `np.argsort` and then index into your dataframe with those:

```
sorted_df = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.max(axis=1))[::-1]]
```

where `np.argsort` gives the indices that would sort the maximum values of each row but in ascending order; so we use `[::-1]` to reverse that to get descending order. `iloc` performs the integer indexing,

to get

```
# sample dataframe
np.random.seed(51)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(size=5),
                   "b": np.random.random(size=5),
                   "c": np.random.random(size=5)})
>>> df

          a         b         c
0  0.675731  0.949338  0.174343
1  0.044712  0.157670  0.218183
2  0.343304  0.387973  0.646746
3  0.644020  0.589994  0.249831
4  0.284213  0.487796  0.410248

>>> sorted_df

          a         b         c
0  0.675731  0.949338  0.174343
2  0.343304  0.387973  0.646746
3  0.644020  0.589994  0.249831
4  0.284213  0.487796  0.410248
1  0.044712  0.157670  0.218183
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!